# Getting Geometry length

Tags: c#, wpf, geometry, system.windows.media

Does anyone know an efficient way of getting the length of a WPF geometry in Pixels?
I know that geometries in WPF are vector based and therefore do not really have a pixellength. But it has to be possible to get the length based on the visible drawn image. I mean if I draw some geometries in a 1024x800 pixel image it has to be possible to get the length of those.

Am I wrong here or is there any possible and efficient way of getting these informations?

Thank you in advance!

Michael

Comment: How do you draw the geometries? Maybe it is possible with a little bit of algebra...

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52645819/7206675) as solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have come up with a solution, but don't know if this would be the most efficent (fastest) way of doing so. Please leave your comments on this - thank you all!

```
    public static double GetLength(this Geometry geo)
    {
        PathGeometry path = geo.GetFlattenedPathGeometry();

        double length = 0.0;

        foreach (PathFigure pf in path.Figures)
        {
            Point start = pf.StartPoint;

            foreach (PolyLineSegment seg in pf.Segments)
            {
                foreach (Point point in seg.Points)
                {
                    length += Distance(start, point);
                    start = point;
                }
            }
        }

        return length;
    }

    private static double Distance(Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(p1.X - p2.X,2) + Math.Pow(p1.Y - p2.Y,2));
    }
```

Comment: This will only work when all segments are straight lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
var geometry = new EllipseGeometry(new Point(50,50), 45, 20);
var length = geometry.Bounds.Width; //or geometry.Bounds.Height
```

Note: `EllipseGeometry` is just an example. All classes that derive from `Geometry` have a `Bounds` property.

Comment: Thanks DanM for your answer! Anyway the example you gave does not really give me the length of the "line" in pixels but the bounding boxes size. A clearer example would be a bounding box of 100x100 pixels size where a zig-zag polyline would be drawn inside. Then the line length (Geometry length) would definetely be much larger than the bounding box.