# To get length of WPF path

Tags: c#, wpf

I have drawn a line using `PathGeometry`.With the reference from [Getting Geometry length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877631/getting-geometry-length) I get the length of path using GetFlattenedPathGeometry method, which will convert path to a series of straight lines, and add up the line lengths.The referred code is

```
public static double GetLength(this Geometry geo)
    {
        PathGeometry path = geo.GetFlattenedPathGeometry();

        double length = 0.0;

        foreach (PathFigure pf in path.Figures)
        {
            Point start = pf.StartPoint;

            foreach (PolyLineSegment seg in pf.Segments)
            {
                foreach (Point point in seg.Points)
                {
                    length += Distance(start, point);
                    start = point;
                }
            }
        }

        return length;
    }

    private static double Distance(Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(p1.X - p2.X,2) + Math.Pow(p1.Y - p2.Y,2));
    }
```

Is there any other better way to get PathGeometry length??

Comment: Consider a path animation with a custom timeline http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970561%28v=vs.110%29.aspx Add ticks until the animation reaches the end. `distance = speed x time` translates to `path_length = animation_speed x ticks_required`.

Comment: Not sure if there is better solution, but definietly you do not need your own Distance function. You can use built in vector support (point-point) returns vector and then you can get length from its properties: `length += (start - point).Length;`

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
public static double GetLengthOfGeo(Geometry geo)
{
    PathGeometry pg = PathGeometry.CreateFromGeometry(geo);
    Point p; Point tp;
    pg.GetPointAtFractionLength(0.0001, out p, out tp);
    return (pg.Figures[0].StartPoint - p).Length*10000;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

With little effort You can convert `System.Windows.Media.Geometry` to `SharpDX.Direct2D1.Geometry` that have [ComputeLength](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/blob/master/Source/SharpDX.Direct2D1/Geometry.cs#L125) function:

> Calculates the length of the geometry as though each segment were
>   unrolled into a line.